# Логический оператор PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Читал код ядра Codeigniter 3 и наткнулся на такую строку:

`isset($index) OR $index = array_keys($array);`

Как это работает? Никогда ещё не видел такого присваивания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая часть выражения проверяет, содержит ли переменная `$index` какое-либо значение, отличное от `NULL`:

- Если `$index === NULL`, то первая часть выражения вернет `false`, значит нам следует проинициализировать переменную.
- Если `$index !== NULL`, значит переменная имеет какое-то значение и часть после `OR` пропускается.

Почему именно так? - Таков принцип работы вычисления логических выражений в PHP, позволяющий не производить ненужные вычисления, которые не приведут к новому результату.

Например, выражение `true OR false`. Первая часть выражения вернет `true`, значит, вторую часть смотреть бессмысленно, т.к. вне зависимости от результата результат будет `true`. Точно так же, в выражении `false AND true` смотреть вторую часть смысла нет - значение выражения в любом случае будет `false`

Если вместо `OR` взять `AND`, то в выражении `true AND false` PHP просмотрит обе его части, т.к. в зависимости от результата второй части значение всего выражения может поменяться.